# Showing inverse composed with function is $x$ for all $x$ in the domain.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is an injection. Show that $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for all $x$ in $D(x)$, and $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$ for all $y$ in $R(f)$. I understand the algebra behind it, and can show this with a random one-to-one function, but don't know where to start such a general proof.

For the first half:
Let $f(x_1)=y_1$  and $f(x_2)=y_2$ 
$\rightarrow$ $f^{-1}(y_1)=x_1$ and $f^{-1}(x_2)=y_2$. 
Using composition, $f^{-1}(f(x_1))=f^{-1}(f(x_2))$ 
$\rightarrow$$f^{-1}(y_1)=f^{-1}(y_2)$ 
$\rightarrow$ $x_1=x_2$

I used similar logic for the second half. Is this correct, or am I just spinning in circles?

Comment: What is your definition of inverse function?

Comment: Yes, it seems itself as the *definition* of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: (Again, I apologize, I'm trying to learn how to code this, and don't have a clue!). Inverse: If f mapping A onto B is a bijection of A onto B, then g:={(b, a) element of BxA: (a,b) element of f} is a function of B into A.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f^{-1}(f(x)) \neq x$ for some $x \in D(f)$. Then $(f(x), x) \notin f^{-1}$. But since
$$\{f^{-1} = \{(b,a): (a,b) \in f\}$$
this means $(x, f(x)) \notin f$ which is a contradiction. The proof of the second assertion is similar.